# Python Iterate over rows and update SQL Server table

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-update

My Python code works to this point and returns several rows. I need to take each row and process it in a loop in Python. The first row works fine and does its trick, but the second row never runs. Clearly, I am not looping correctly. I believe I am not iterating over each row in the results. Here is the code:

```py
for row in results:
    print(row[0])
    
    F:\FinancialResearch\SEC\myEdgar\sec-edgar-filings\A\10-K\0000014693-21-000091\full-submission.txt
    F:\FinancialResearch\SEC\myEdgar\sec-edgar-filings\A\10-K\0000894189-21-001890\full-submission.txt
    F:\FinancialResearch\SEC\myEdgar\sec-edgar-filings\A\10-K\0000894189-21-001895\full-submission.txt
    
for row in results:
    with open(row[0],'r') as f:
        contents = f.read()
        bill = row
        for x in range(0, 3):
            VanHalen = 'Hello'
            cnxn1 = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
            'Server=XXX;'
            'Database=00010KData;'
            'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
            
            curs1 = cnxn1.cursor()
            curs1.execute('''
                        Update EdgarComments SET Comments7 = ? WHERE FullPath = ?
                        ''', (VanHalen,bill))
            curs1.commit()
            curs1.close()
            cnxn1.close()
            print(x)
```

Error: ('HY004', '[HY004] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid SQL data type (0) (SQLBindParameter)')

Answer (score 0):

The `bill` variable that you are storing in the FullPath column contains all the rows - is this what you want?

I would normally expect to see the file path (`row[0]`) being stored given the column name `FullPath`.

Since this is an Invalid Type error on the binding parameters, you can always check the type of the `bill` variable before inserting and make sure it is a type that the SQL driver accepts - usually you wanna convert strange types to strings before using them as binding-params.

Comment: Thank you, the bill variable has many rows of file paths and I want each  row inserted into the table in a loop along with other, associated data. I have it working for one row but I can't seem to make it iterate.